# How do I start the test class SpringbootTwitter4jDemoApplicationTest in following spring boot project twitter4j-spring-boot-sample?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat, test-class

I've downloaded and cloned maven project successfully and as well imported it as maven project.

I can run the main class in tomcat server[server console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdYYH.png) but there is test class SpringbootTwitter4jDemoApplicationTest that I want to run but I couldn't.

link to github repo: https://github.com/sivaprasadreddy/twitter4j-spring-boot-starter.git

I also try to run it from terminal with mvn clean install and change to directory where test class is and executed mvn clean test seen here:[mvn clean install command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCMax.png)[mvn clean test part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMcCF.png)
[mvn clean test part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5PQa.png)
What do I need to do?

Thank you for your advise friends

[this is the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpP5N.png)

Comment: Lots of image posted, does anyone want to read from images??

Comment: Thank you Kopi for your comment. It is my first question in StackOverFlow. I will post the execution of mvn commands as log. And as well the classes. But will keep one screen shot of eclipse to show the project structure.